# Speed up random set partition code

Tags: performance-tuning, random, sets

I have managed to construct code for randomly generating a set partition of size n with k parts. Note that the total number of such objects is counted by a [Stirling number of the second kind](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind).

The code is very simple; there are two cases for the largest entry `n`. Either it is in its own block, or not. It is easy to compute the probability for the first case,
and then one uses recursion.

```
RandomSetPartition[0, k_Integer] := Which[k == 0, {{}}, {}];
RandomSetPartition[1, k_Integer] := Which[k == 1, {{1}}, {}];
RandomSetPartition[n_Integer, 1] := {Range@n};
RandomSetPartition[n_Integer, n_Integer] := List /@ (Range@n);

RandomSetPartition[n_Integer, k_Integer] := If[
   RandomReal[] <= StirlingS2[n - 1, k - 1]/StirlingS2[n, k],
   Append[RandomSetPartition[n - 1, k - 1], {n}], 
   MapAt[Append[#, n] &, RandomSetPartition[n - 1, k], 
    RandomInteger[{1, k}]]
   ];
```

The issue is, the code is rather slow for large arguments, say `RandomSetPartition[1000,30]` takes about 2 seconds on my machine.
I am not sure what the issue with my code is; the complexity should be O(n),
but some tests indicate the complexity is higher for my code.
What can I change to make it more efficient?

Comment: Your `Which` do not work, but you do not need them.

Answer (score 1):

*I rewrote this answer completely. The previous answer is available [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/revisions/276514/4).*

In OP's code, the StirlingS2 calls are expensive for large $n$. For example, calling

```
StirlingS2[4500,2111]
```

for the first time takes about 1 second on my machine. From OPs comment I understand that they want to call RandomSetPartition with say $n=20000$ and with many different values of $k$. The solution presented here was designed with that case in mind.

**Code.** Run the following once, with `nmax` equal to the largest value that one is planning to use:

```
nmax=2000;
s2prev={1.};
Do[
   s2=Append[Range[n-1]*s2prev+Prepend[Most[s2prev],0.],1.];
   sq[n]=Quiet[Developer`ToPackedArray[N[s2prev/Rest[s2]]]];
   s2prev=s2;
,{n,2,nmax}];

(* this is equal to N[StirlingS2[n-1,k-1]/StirlingS2[n,k]] *)
squot[n_,1]:=0.;
squot[n_,k_]:=sq[n][[k-1]];
```

This takes about $2$ seconds for `nmax=2000`, and it takes about $6$ minutes for `nmax=20000`. Since this has to be done only once, it seems acceptable.

Random set partitions can then be generated using

```
rSow[n_Integer,n_Integer]:=Scan[Sow[#,#]&,Range[n]];
rSow[n_Integer,k_Integer]:=rSow[n-1,If[RandomReal[]<=squot[n,k],
  Sow[n,k];k-1,
  Sow[n,RandomInteger[{1,k}]];k]];
RandomSetPartition[n_Integer,k_Integer]:=Block[{$IterationLimit=Infinity},
  Flatten[Last[Reap[rSow[n,k],Range[k]]],1]];
```

**Example:**

```
SeedRandom[1];
RandomSetPartition[10,5]
(* {{10,8,1},{2},{9,6,5,3},{4},{7}} *)
```

**Timing:**

```
First[RepeatedTiming[RandomSetPartition[2000,1000]]]
(* 0.00909227 *)

First[RepeatedTiming[RandomSetPartition[20000,10000]]]
(* 0.111011 *)
```

**Comments:**

- The code for `squot` uses the [recurrence relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind#Recurrence_relation) for StirlingS2. It is also written to keep memory footprint reasonably low.
- The code for `RandomSetPartition` is a direct adaptation of OP's code. It uses `Reap`-`Sow` instead of `Append`. It also uses tail recursion.

Comment: Ok, so the speedup here is basically for repeated samples. The first random set partition still needs some warmup, in order to compute all the Stirling number quotients, correct?

Comment: Yes exactly. I am just pointing out where your code spends all its time. Memoization is one approach. Instead of memoization, you could maybe also use approximate formulas for StirlingS2 (or for your particular quotient of StirlingS2) that are accurate enough and much easier to evaluate (I have not looked into that though). Depends on what you want to do.

Comment: I was hoping to be able to generate a random set partition with n about 20.000, but that might be too slow. Perhaps one can deduce some sort of recursion of the quotients of stirling numbers via the classical stirling number recursion.

Comment: If $n=20000$ and $k<2000$ or so, then you can use the 4th implementation, which does not use memoization at all. For example, `RandomSetPartition4[20000,1000]` takes about 0.008 seconds. But I am confident that also the ones using `StirlingS2` can be made to work using the [various properties](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind#Properties). I also tried [DiscreteAsymptotic](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DiscreteAsymptotic.html) but did not manage to get a useful result.

Comment: So, I am in fact looking for picking a set partition (no k) uniformly, so I need to pick among all possible values of k; in order to make the weighted choice, I then need the Stirling numbers for all k, for n=20000. But it is nice to know that the Stirling numbers are the bottleneck...